# Proving that a set of operations can't generate one integer from a given one

Tags: algorithms, number-theory, search-problem

Given two numbers, $n$ and $m$, are there some mathematical methods of deducing $m$ from $n$ using limited number of elemantary operations?

Example:  335 can be deduced from 2000 using division by 2, addition of 5 and division by 3: $((2000/2)+5)/3) = 335$.

I need to prove that 1889 can't be derived from 2019 using the following 3 operations:

1. $n+7$ ;
2. $n*2$;
3. $n/3$ (if divisible).

All I come up with is some sort of breadth-first search.

Answer (score 3):

If you have implemented breadth first search correctly, you should have found that 1889 can be reached.

$\quad 2019+7\to 2026$
$\quad 2026+7\to 2033$
$\quad\quad\cdots\quad$ (add 7 repeatedly)
$\quad 4238+7\to 4245$
$\quad 4245 \div 3 \to 1415$
$\quad 1415 * 2 \to 2830$
$\quad 2830 * 2 \to 5660$
$\quad 5660 + 7 \to 5667$
$\quad 5667 \div 3 \to 1889$

It is possible that you had been asked to show that 1883 can't be derived from 2019.

#### A number can be derived from 2019 iff it is a positive integer not divisible by 7

**Proof**:
"$\Longrightarrow$": If $n$ is not divisible by 7, neither is any of $n+7$, $n*2$ and $n/3$ (when $n$ is divisible by 3). If we start with a number that is not divisible by 7, it will remain not divisible by 7 regardless of how many operations we have applied on it. Since 2019 is not divisible by 7, we cannot derive any number that is divisible by 7.

"$\Longleftarrow$":

In fact, we can derive all positive numbers not divisible by 7 without the operation $n\to n * 2$. For all $k\ge0$,

- $\dfrac{2019 + 7 * (((7k+1)*3^{6k+7}-2019)/7)}{3^{6k+7}}=7k+1$
- $\dfrac{2019 + 7 * (((7k+2)*3^{6k+11}-2019)/7)}{3^{6k+11}}=7k+2$
- $\dfrac{2019 + 7 * (((7k+3)*3^{6k+6}-2019)/7)}{3^{6k+6}}=7k+3$
- $\dfrac{2019 + 7 * (((7k+4)*3^{6k+9}-2019)/7)}{3^{6k+9}}=7k+4$
- $\dfrac{2019 + 7 * (((7k+5)*3^{6k+8}-2019)/7)}{3^{6k+8}}=7k+5$
- $\dfrac{2019 + 7 * (((7k+6)*3^{6k+10}-2019)/7)}{3^{6k+10}}=7k+6$

#### Exercises

**Exercise 1.** Assume the same three operations. Let $n$ be a positive number not divisible by 7. Then a number can be derived from $n$ iff it is a positive integer not divisible by 7.

**Exercise 2.** Assume the same three operations. Let $n$ be a positive number divisible by 7. Then a number can be derived from $n$ iff it is divisible by 7.

**Exercise 3.** If positive integer $m$ can be derived from positive integer $n$ using the three operations, then $m$ can be derived from $n$ using the first and last operations, namely, $n\to n+7$ and $n\to n/3$ (if divisible).

Comment: I think you meant "remainder" instead of reminder. Did you may also mean remainders of numbers divided by 3 instead of 7?

Comment: I mean 7. Does 3 work for you?

Comment: Probably I need to clarify the question. All this operations should be done on number derived from initial number. 2019 - 1 level. 2019+7=2026, 2019*2=4038, 2019/3=673 - 2 level. Then we break 2026 from 2 level again 2026+7=2033, 2026*2=4052, 2026/3=with remainder (we don't need it anymore). And so for every integer that we meet executing this 3 operations.Next will be 4038 ...

Comment: $2019+7=2026$. Then $2026+7=2033$. Then $2033+7=2040$.  Then $2040+7=2047$. Then $2047+7=2054$. Then $\cdots$ (many steps of adding 7). Then $4238+7=4245$.

Comment: @cs_student You mean, that we have a additional rule? Here, we have to (1.): add 7; then (2.) multiply with 2 and last (3.) divide by 3 if possible, otherwise start from step 1 again? Then this problem is way more easier. I asked my algorithmics professor and he immediately conjected that this problem would be $NP-complete$ or even $EXPTIME$-hard if we can arbitrarely shuffle the composition of functions since they dont form a composition ring. .

Comment: @Panzerkroete, cs_student said, "Next will be 4038".

Comment: @Apass.Jack I should read more carefully ;) I will add an expontential time pseudocode algorithm in my anser briefly

Answer (score 0):

Define $f(x) = x/3, g(x) = 2x, h(x) = x+7$ and $D = \mathbb{N}$ for the functions $f,g,h$. I presume that the question is the following:
Given $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$  is there a transformation sequence $s_{(n)}:= (f \circ g \circ h) ^{n}$ such that $(f \circ g \circ h) ^{n}(x) = y)$ with the restriction that always $3 | (g\circ h)(f \circ g \circ h) ^{n-1}(x)$ ?

Now write $s_{(n)}$ as a direct expression depending only on $x,n$. Lets call this $c(x,n)$. 
Here $c(x,n) = \frac{2^nx+14(2^n-1)}{3^n}$ For simplicity we write also $c(x,n):=\frac{num(x,n)}{3^n}$

Given $x,y$, then $y$ can be derived from $x$ iff $c(x,n)=y$ has a has at least one natural solution for $n$ and $3^i | num(x,i)$ for all $i \leq n, i \in \mathbb{N}$.

Applied this result to the conrete numbers, we see that the positive $n \approx 0.166$ and hence 1889 can not be derived from 2019.

If there are no restrictions on the composition of the function, this problem is (according to my professor) at least $NP$-complete. A formal proof would be nice, until now I didnt find a suitable Problem for a sharp reduction.